# Rails 4 Seeding Devise Admins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've seen a few questions as to how to go about seeding users / admins / people through devise but none of them were working for me and I'd assume it's because I am using rails4.

I really just need one seed.  So I put this directly into my seed file

```
        admin = Admin.new
        admin.email = 'adminone@gmail.com'
        admin.password = "topsecret"
        admin.password_confirmation = "topsecret"
        admin.save!
```

That did not work...

Neither did this...

```
admin = Admin.create! :name => 'John Doe', :email => 'john@gmail.com', :password => 'topsecret', :password_confirmation => 'topsecret'
```

The seed functions, but when I try to login, I get invalid combination.

Thoughts? I'm using

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, 
    :registerable,
    #:recoverable, 
    :rememberable, 
    :trackable, 
    :validatable
```

for my model.

Update:  This is my entire ApplicationController.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :set_mail
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def set_mail
      @mail_subscriber = MailSubscriber.new(mail_subscriber_params)
  end
private

def current_cart 
  cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  unless cart.active?
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  end
  cart
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  cart
 end
 def mail_subscriber_params
  params.fetch(:mail_subscriber, {}).permit(:email, :name)
 end 
end
```

Update #2

```
admin.valid_password?("topsecret")
```

gives me, so the seed must not have worked?

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
```

Comment: Can you please post your `configure_permitted_parameters` configuration from `application_controller.rb`?

Comment: You tell us the seed functions, yet the question is about how to seed. Can you confirm that the seed is saved and that the password is correct? On the console you can find the user and then do `user.valid_password?("topsecret")` to confirm the password is correct as seeded.

Comment: I guess the seed didn't save I get -- BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Admin.create! :email => 'john@gmail.com', :password => 'topsecret', :password_confirmation => 'topsecret'
```

Did not work but

```
Admin.create :email => 'john@gmail.com', :password => 'topsecret', :password_confirmation => 'topsecret'
```

did work.  The difference was the ! after the 'create'

Hopefully this helps people who run into this issue in the future